# How to get specific class element of table?(duplicate class)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have 2 tables with same class elements like:

```
<table class="myTbl">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

```
 <table class="myTbl">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>C</th>
    <th>D</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

When I add jquery function like
`$(function(){  $('.myTbl tbody').function() })`

I want the function only run in specific table like table 1 , but I'm having duplicate classes. How to do it?

And I cant affect the html table like change class or add id,... cause It's exported from other, only js or jquery to do it.

I tried `$('.myTbl tbody:nth-child(1)')` not working.

Comment: [`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq)

Comment: Select first table: `document.querySelector(".myTbl")` or `document.querySelectorAll(".myTbl")[0]`

Comment: omg just so easy.... Thanks!

Comment: `$(".myTbl:first tbody")` or `$(".myTbl:nth-of-type(1) tbody")` too

Comment: Also how to do it in css? Thanks again.

Comment: Do what in CSS?  `.myTbl:first tbody` and `.myTbl:nth-of-type(1) tbody` will access the first table's tbody if that is what you want

Answer (score 0):

you can do that with adding .eq(0) to your code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".myTbl tbody").eq(0).click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<table class="myTbl">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>C</th>
    <th>D</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<hr/>

<table class="myTbl">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add one more class to the element that you want to select, or you can also select by index of all selected elements.

```
  <!--Consider the following example: -->

    <p class="para">Paragraph1</p>
    <p class="para">Paragraph2</p>
    <p class="para">Paragraph3</p>
    <p class="para">Paragraph3</p>
    <script>
    const paragraphs = document.getElementByClassName("para");
    console.log(paragraphs[0]) //outputs the first paragraph
    console.log(paragraphs[1]) //outputs the second paragrah
    console.log(paragraphs[3]) //outputs the third paragraph
        //similarly you can select in jquery too
    </script>
```